# simpleton javascript question - how do I fade this in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read the docs but still a bit confused. I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trynow').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenContent').dialog({ height: 700, width: 600, modal: true });
    });                          
});
```

that uses the jquery UI library to show a modal box with a form in it. I'd like both the background and modal box to fade in or fade out and I know there the options to do that with jquery and the UI plugin but I'm buggered if I can figure out what wraps what where and in what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ (click on `animated dialog` on the right).

```
$('#trynow').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenContent').dialog({
        height: 700,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade'
    });
});
```

You can also use a different animation on `show` than on `hide`. Try using `hide: 'explode'`, it's really cool.

Comment: Also of note is you can't control the speed of that fade in animation right now.

Comment: thanks for the info. I thought I had tried that so must have had a typo or something first time round. Grr.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Try setting the show property to 'fade',the doc says that at least 'slide' is supported.

```
$('#hiddenContent').dialog({ height: 700, width: 600, modal: true, show: 'fade' })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trynow').click(function(){
        $('#hiddenContent').dialog({ height: 700, width: 600, modal: true, show: 'fade', hide:'fade' });
    });                          
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Toukakoukan/UG6m6/)